# How to map array using ObjectMapper?

Tags: ios, swift, objectmapper

## Here is my model

```
class ResponseDataType: Mappable {

    var status: Int?
    var message: String?
    var info: [Info]?

    required init?(map: Map) { }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        status <- map["status"]
        message <- map["message"]
        info <- map["member_info"]
    }
}
```

## Here is my JSON

```
"status": 200,
    "data": {
        "member_info": [
            {
                "fullname": "werwerwer",
                "type": "werwer",
                "profile_image": "sdfsdfsd.jpg",
                "email": "wfwe@werwegt",
                "contact": ""
            }
        ]
    },
    "message": "Login Success"
}
```

Im having a hard time mapping the array inside the data. Please tell me what is wrong with my code.

Comment: Is there a good reason for not using Codable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the data. It should be like this:

```
class ResponseDataType: Mappable {

var status: Int?
var message: String?
var data: Data?

required init?(map: Map) { }

func mapping(map: Map) {
    status <- map["status"]
    message <- map["message"]
    data <- map["data"]
}
```

and your data class:

```
class Data: Mappable {

var info: [Info]?

required init?(map: Map) { }

func mapping(map: Map) {
    info <- map["member_info"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Info object conforms to Mappable, everything should work properly in your code. But try to read about Codable protocol, it’s much easier to map objects with it!